# In lines 16,54,55,56,57,58 i get the error "Statement missing ; in function main()" WHY?

Tags: c++

In lines 16,54,55,56,57,58 I get the error

> Statement missing ; in function main()

WHY?

And in 31 I get

> expression syntax in function main()

I'm trying n resistors categorize them into 2 categories based on 4 resistors values

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int n;
 float V,TOTAL1,TOTAL2;
 int r1,r2,r3,r4,i;
 cout << "Give r1: ";//Im asking for resitors.
 cin >> r1;
 cout << "Give r2: ";
 cin >> r2;
 cout << "Give r3: ";
 cin >> r3;
 cout << "Give r4: ";
 cin >> r4;
 cout "Give voltage: ";
 cin >> V;
 cout << "Give number of resistors: ";
 cin >> n;
 for(i=1;i<n+1;i++)
{
  float value;
  int m;
  m=0;
  m=m+1;
  cout << "Give resistane: ";
  cin >> value;
  int a,b;//I try to count the number on its category.
  a=0;
  b=0;
  if(value>=r1) && (value>=r2) && (value<=r3) && (value<=r4)
  {
   if(m%2>0)
   {
    cout << "It belongs to the first";
    a=a+1;
    TOTAL1=value+TOTAL1;//If they are in the first category they are connected in series
   }
    else
   {
     cout << "It belongs to the second";
     b=b+1;
     1/TOTAL2=1/value + 1/TOTAL2;
    }
  else if(value>=r1)&&(value<=r2)
  cout << "It belongs to the first";
  a=a+1;
  TOTAL1=value+TOTAL1;
  else if(value>=r3)&&(value<=r4)
  cout << "It belongs to the second";
  b=b+1;
  1/TOTAL2=1/value + 1/TOTAL2;
  }
 }
 cout << "\n The first category has: " a;
 cout << "\n The second category has: " b; 
 cout << "\n The yotal resistance of the first category is: " TOTAL1; 
 cout << "\n The total resistance of the second category is: " 1/(1/TOTAL2); 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you there's an error at line 16, did you look there?

Comment: `1/TOTAL2=1/value + 1/TOTAL2;` this isn't a valid assignment expression.

Comment: Given the number of typos, I think it's a fair recommendation that you check your code for any errors *before* writing this much.

Answer (score 2):

On line 16 did you intend to put:

```
cout << "Give voltage: ";
```

instead of:

```
cout "Give voltage: ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parens:

```
if(value>=r1) && (value>=r2) && (value<=r3) && (value<=r4)
```

should be:

```
if ((value>=r1) && (value>=r2) && (value<=r3) && (value<=r4))
```

Similarly in a few other places.